# Custom control binding is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm having trouble getting my binding to work correctly. Basically I have this, call this Control1.xaml. The commented out portion of the code binds correctly and updates as expected.

```
    <progControls:CalibrationSummary

    </progControls:CalibrationSummary>

    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfCalibrations, Mode=OneWay}"/>-->
```

However, if I put that commented code in a custom control called CalibrationsSummary.xaml, I cannot bind this to NumberOfCalibrations.

Here's what CalibrationsSummary looks like

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfCalibrations, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Note that I do use RelativeSource to try to get the property associated with Control1.xaml, tried TemplateBinding also. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are going to create reusable controls, use dependency properties for `NumberOfCalibrations`.  Controls should have their own VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CalibrationSummary` has no `TemplatedParent` unless you have put it in a ControlTemplate.

If you don't explicitly set the `DataContext` of the property of `CalibrationSummary` somewhere, it will inherit the `DataContext` from its parent control (which I assume is `Control1`) and then you can bind any property of this control's `DataContext` as usual without specifying any source:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfCalibrations}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I had to add a "Mode = OneWay" in order for it to show up like expected for some reason. Without it, it wouldn't work. Thanks for teaching me and pointing me in the right track!